# Как сделать что-бы бот отправлял сообщения в заданное время?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Как сделать так что-бы бот в телеграме отправлял определенное сообщение, например 'Привет как дела?' в 10:00 и в 20:00?

Comment: используйте `import schedule`, и потом `schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(send_message_dunction)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вам нужно использовать модуль schedule, который позволяет планировать задачи по времени

```
import schedule
import time
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("token")

def send_message():
    bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Привет, как дела?')

schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(send_message)
schedule.every().day.at("20:00").do(send_message)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

мы создаём функцию `send_message`, которая отправляет сообщение через бота. Затем мы планируем её запуск каждый день в 10:00 и 20:00 с помощью метода `schedule.every().day.at()`. в конце, в цикле `while` мы запускаем все запланированные задачи и ждём 1 секунду.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо! Все работает как нужно.

Comment: @Nazar вы можете благодарить автора приняв вопрос и проголосовав вверх